How to validate and decode azure ad jwt token in springboot api application?
I have springboot api application that is consumed by react app.
Inside react app I get authenticated to azure ad and get back jwt idToken which is sent to springboot api.
What I would like to do is to validate received token and extract user info inside springboot app in order to add that user to the app based on received info.
How can I do that using spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client?
I am trying to create azure ad authentication for my app.I tried going trough the docs and cant seem to find where to start. I am expecting to get idToken validated and to have info about user in order to process it further.
I cant seem to find relevant documentation and would appreciate any help pointing me in the right direction.

thats not the purpose of  spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client the client is used to log in the user, what you are looking for is oauth2 resource server and is documented here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/index.html

ID tokens are not access tokens and should not be used to authorize requests.
Single-Page Applications can't keep a secret. As a consequence, it can only be "public" OAuth2 clients. It is safer to use only "confidential" OAuth2 clients (on your servers). For that, you should have a look at this Baeldung article I wrote. It describes how to configure spring-cloud-gateway as an OAuth2 BFF in front of (stateless) resource server(s): a confidential client bridging between authorization based on sessions cookies for the frontend and authorization based on bearer tokens for the REST API(s).

keycloak is not azure

OpenID is OpenID. What I state in this answer is true for any OpenID provider.
